# How to escape all markdown characters with a backslash?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to escape all markdown characters with a backslash `\`.

I've tried

```
"testing _the thing".gsub /(\*|_|`)/, '\\\1'
```

And the result is:

```
testing \\_the thing
```

With only 2 `\\`

```
"testing _the thing".gsub /(\*|_|`)/, '\\1'
 => "testing _the thing"
```

The output I would like is:

```
 => "testing \_the thing"
```

I've tried many things without luck.

Comment: Maybe try using `\\\\\1`...

Comment: What you are trying to match or replace?

Comment: @l'L'l already tried, not working, result is double `\ `, like `"testing \\_the \\*thing"`

Comment: @hellio6 I'm trying to match any *, _ or ` and prepend a _ in front of those characters

Comment: Over at APIDock, the user @mange has an explanation what's going on with escape characters when used with `gsub` and a match reference: https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub#787-Replacing-with-and-match

Comment: Is there a good duplicate target for this? This exact same question gets asked so often over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over again, I see no point in answering it over and over again; I would much rather prefer it being closed quickly as a duplicate. (Actually, I see no point in asking it over and over again, but that's a different story.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the right output. In `inspect` mode you'll see this:

```
"\\_"
```

That means "*literal*-backslash underscore". Remember that inside double-quoted strings the backslash is used for special characters and sequences like `\t` for tab or `\n` for newline. A backslash *must* be escaped if you want an actual backslash.

Try this:

```
puts "\\_"
```

You'll see just `\_` like you want.

If you do this:

```
"\_"
```

That's "*literal*-underscore", which of course is just an underscore. The backslash ends up disappearing since it's redundant.